# moment code to convert Singapore time to UTC time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I wrote the below code to convert singapore time to UTC time.

```
 function convert(time) {

          let eventStartTime = moment(time, 'HH:mm', 'Singapore').utc().format('HH:mm');

   return eventStartTime;
  }
```

when I ran the below line

```
  convert('19:00');
```

It is giving me the output as 23:00 which is incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The above code works and returns '02:00' which is correct. I've added your code into a JSFiddle to test: http://jsfiddle.net/o9L6e5xp/. I suspect there's more going on than this simple example and something else interferes with your output.

Comment: @André your fiddle returns 23:00 for me

Comment: @André  your fiddle is returning 23:00 to me

Comment: Also, shouldn't the correct time be 11:00 as Singapore is 8 hours ahead of GMT?

Comment: @SuperStormer correct , it should return 11:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex's answer has the right explanation for why this current approach doesn't work. However, we can also fix this by using `moment-timezone`:

```js
function convert(time) {
  let eventStartTime = moment.tz(time, 'HH:mm', 'Asia/Singapore').utc().format('HH:mm');
  return eventStartTime;
}

alert(convert('19:00'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.33/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

This requires you to use `moment.js` >= 2.60 though.

Answer (score 3):

```
function convert(time) {
  let eventStartTime = moment(time + ' +0800', 'HH:mm Z',).utc().format('HH:mm');
  return eventStartTime;
}

alert(convert('19:00'))
```

seems to work for me

I don't think that it is interpreting the third argument how you had it, so it is just counting that as local time for me, and converting 7pm in my local timezone to UTC

I just followed this example using @andré's jsfiddle:

```
moment("2010-10-20 4:30 +0000", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z"); // parsed as 4:30 UTC
```

from https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/

It says in the docs that if you want to use something like `Asia/Singapore` you should use this: https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: :facepalm: I should've realized that the timezone offset was gmt-4 instead of gmt+8. Looks like the 3rd string argument is supposed to be for the locale instead.